# Concurrent Read - Reading different rows from same table by different java application instance in using jpa hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am writing a scheduler in spring boot, which will do the following action.

1. read the 2 rows from a table (database - oracle)
2. do some operation.
3. Then update one field value of the rows read in step 1.

When I will run my application as two separate instances, 2 schedulers will run.

Which will make all the above steps repeated in 2 times.

My goal is if the schedule of the 1st instance is reading 2 rows at that time schedule of the 2nd instance to read next 2 rows, instead of the same row.

Please suggest any way to do this using JPA or in Java.

Answer (score 1):

So let's have a look at your requirements:

1. Each process instance should read two rows from some table
2. A two-row-set worked on by one process should be off limits for any other process
3. You don't want to *wait* for one process to finish the first two-row-set before the seconds process picks up its two rows

Now how to solve them?

1. That's basic - you already have that, right?
2. Could be done different ways, so let's first look at
3. No blocking. That implies: Any of your processes being started has to be *aware* of the rows the other processes are working on

So you need some kind of "reservation" on the two rows the process is going to handle.

I'd handle it this way:

- add a lock column into your table as this marker of "I'm currently worked at"
- modify your selection query to ignore already locked columns AND
- modify your selection query `FOR UPDATE`, preventing other processes from doing the same. (Yes, that IS blocking others, but only while you're at it)
- Now update both rows to set the lock marker or your process
- Do what you have to do
- when you're ready for your step 3 (update field), reset lock marker.

You might want to take extra measures in terms of one process dying after setting lock-marker but before releasing them which could eventually lead to rows never processed - maybe us a timestamp value in lock column and select for lock based on reasonable time delta (process runs every 10 minutes - eveeything older than 30min is probably crashed)